# Quill Angular Error: NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken config

Tags: angular, quill, ngx-quill

I updated all my node modules and when quill updated, all my editors broke in my application. The error "NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken config!" appeared.

I Have fixed this problem! Just wanted to share with other ppl who might be in the same boat.

You need to add the QuillModule (import { QuillModule } from 'ngx-quill';) to the App Module 'Imports' section (or whatever module you are using). For me, I also needed to add .forRoot() to make it work

```
imports: [
    QuillModule.forRoot(),
],
```

Again, this works for me, just letting you all know in case you encounter the same problem updating ngx-quill to the newest version

Comment: you have asked the question and tell the solution within the question, Better would be to make it as answer separately.

Comment: thank you. it is really helpful

Comment: I had the same problem, your solution fixes it :) Thank you!

Comment: Can't thank you enough but this **GEM** was hidden in rubble! I skipped your question and was searching for the answer on the answers section. Please move the answer portion to answers and keep the question separate!

Answer (score 5):

First You have to import QUILL_CONFIG_TOKEN from 'ngx-quill' library after that you have to pass this class to inject eg
QuillModule.forRoot(QUILL_CONFIG_TOKEN.ngInjectableDef)